# Enable 2nd Monitor (TV) Only When Powered On

Tags: linux-mint, multi-monitor

I am running Linux Mint 18 and have my PC setup with two displays. Both are large, flatscreen televisions.

My question is this: Is it possible to somehow detect when the second display is turned on and enable dual monitors only in that situation?

For example, right now, if I don't want to use my second display, I always go into the display settings and disable it; I then need to manually re-enable dual monitors when I turn on the second TV.

Can this be automated in some way?

I have only one video card, a GeForce 750 Ti, using the proprietary drivers. My main display is connected via HDMI and the secondary is DVI.

Comment: It could be a *hardware* thing. I don't know if DVI or HDMI are transmitting to the computer the current status of the monitor. Perhaps you need to query *periodically* the monitor (and I don't know exactly how). The question becomes "how to detect that a DVI monitor has been switched on?"